# Node-red call a function or update variable in template

Tags: node-red

Node-red call a function or update variable in template

I have an html template and I have some jqueryui sliders thst when I move I would like them to update a red node variable.

Can this be done without making a post request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to some way communicate from the page back to Node-RED you have 3 real options

1. A HTTP GET/POST to a *HTTP IN* node
2. Open a Websocket connection from the page to a *Websocket IN* node
3. Use MQTT over Websockets to publish the changes to a broker and then have a *MQTT IN* node

Any of these can then flow into a function node to change a flow/global variable that can be picked up by the template node next time it's envoked

Answer (score 0):

A potential option worth examining is the use of the `node-red-contrib-ui` package that can be read about at the `npm` web site here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-ui

What this package does is provide a very elegant mechanism for a Node-RED flow to describe a browser screen layout itself.  This can include buttons, text input, gauges, charts and ... in your case ... sliders.  When the user interacts with the page, those interactions themselves cause flow instances to be created.  What this means is that there is no communication between a separate web page and Node-RED as Node-RED is itself generating the page.  It also appears that one can insert arbitrary HTML which might be applicable to leveraging jQuery UI and other UI browser technologies.

This technology inverts the story with the focus being placed on Node-RED and the UI being secondary but it is still worthy of contemplation even for deciding that it is not what you need for your current project.